# Getting Error While Dumping Data From Hive to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive, hue

I am facing the following issues while dumping data from Hive to MongoDB. The Commands I was running are:

1)

> create external table mongo_users(memberid string,email string,sentdate string,actiontype string,actiondate string,campaignid string,campaignname string)  stored by "org.yong3.hive.mongo.MongoStorageHandler"  with serdeproperties ( "mongo.column.mapping" = "memberid,email,sentdate,actiontype,actiondate,campaignid,campaignname" )  tblproperties ( "mongo.host" = "serverip", "mongo.port" = "port",  "mongo.db" = "admin", "mongo.collection" = "dummy" );

2)
`insert into table mongo_users select * from testmail;`

The Description of the Tables:

```
Mongo_Users

memberid        string  from deserializer
email           string  from deserializer
sentdate        string  from deserializer
actiontype      string  from deserializer
actiondate      string  from deserializer
campaignid      string  from deserializer
campaignname    string  from deserializer
```

TestMail Table:

```
memberid        string
email   string
sentdate        string
actiontype      string
actiondate      string
campaignid      string
campaignname    string
```

Error Hive is throwing:

```
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"memberid":"1","email":"George1@gmail.com","sentdate":"1st June 2012","actiontype":"Bounced","actiondate":"4-Jun","campaignid":"51674","campaignname":"Brand Awareness"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"memberid":"1","email":"George1@gmail.com","sentdate":

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set the HIVE auxpath

command is as follows.

hive --auxpath /home/hadoop/mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar,/home/hadoop/hive-mongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Along with the above jars you also need to add jars which is required of the execution of the hive scripts.

creating mongo table

create external table mongo_users(student_id INT,email_id STRING,delivery_status STRING)  stored by "org.yong3.hive.mongo.MongoStorageHandler"  with serdeproperties ("mongo.column.mapping" = "student_id,email_id,delivery_status" ) tblproperties ( "mongo.host" = "ServerName", "mongo.port" = "port",  "mongo.db" = "admin", "mongo.user" = "admin", "mongo.passwd" = "admin", "mongo.collection" = "testing" );

insert data to mongo from hive:

insert overwrite table mongo_users select student_id, email_id, delivery_status from avro_table;